# union on certain columns created from join?

Tags: mysql

The trouble I've been having with union is that the tables your querying must have all the same columns. Is there a way to query using an join with a union on ONLY certain coloumns?

```
SELECT Client.Client_ID, Client.First_Name, Client.Last_Name, Client.Company_Name from Client
union 
select Agency_Employee.Employee_ID, Agency_Employee.First_Name, Agency_Employee.Last_Name, ''
from Agency_Employee
union
select Agency_ID, '', '', Agency_Name from Admin_Agency
SELECT proj.ProjectID, A.Project_Title, B.Account_ID, B.Username, B.Access_Type FROM Project_Assigned proj

JOIN Account B
    ON proj.AccountID = B.Account_ID
JOIN Project A
    ON proj.ProjectID = A.Project_ID

WHERE proj.ProjectID = 1;
```

In the above above I'm trying to combine a join query created which matches accounts assigned to project 1 and with union I'm trying to get additional information such as first_name, last_name from those account numbers from different tables such as client, agency_employee.

Comment: @SabeenMalik the problem is not the column names, it's the column count.

Comment: In terms of the question, I'm not sure I understand. Can you please provide sample table data for your (apparently) three source tables, and the result set you'd like to get to?

Comment: @Romain thanks I totally forgot that MySQL uses the names from the first select!

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is.
You can do it by specifying the names of the columns- they should be the same.
In your case you can do it like that:

```
SELECT Client.Client_ID, Client.First_Name, Client.Last_Name, Client.Company_Name from Client
union 
select Agency_Employee.Employee_ID as Client_ID, Agency_Employee.First_Name, Agency_Employee.Last_Name, '' as Company_Name
from Agency_Employee
union
select Agency_ID as Client_ID, '' as First_Name, '' as Last_Name, Agency_Name as Company_Name from Admin_Agency
```

I don't see in your code how exactly you want to merge your union with the following queries but you can do it with sub-queries. Here is the example:

```
select a.item1, b.count from table_a a
inner join (
     select item1, count(*) as count
     from table_b
     group by item1
) b on b.item1 = a.item1
```

Comment: The trouble I'm having is how do I add this to the join created in the query.

Comment: you can do it as sub_query like this:
select a.item1, b.count from table_a a
inner join (
select item1, count(*) as count
from table_b
group by item1
) b on b.item1 = a.item1